# Matrix whose rows have different column names in R

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

I'd like to have a matrix-like data structure in R, where each row has different column names. Essentially, I'd like almost a list of dictionaries.

Consider the following code:

```
x <- c(.5, .3, .2)
y <- c(.1, .6, .3)
names(x) <- c("foo", "bar", "foobar")
names(y) <- sample(names(x)) #same tokens, different order. 
a <- rbind(x, y)
a
```

The result is a matrix a, whose rows all have entries named after the column names of the matrix.  I'd like for each row to have its own names.

// MOTIVATION

Slightly more concretely, consider a matrix like you might receive as output from the Latent Dirichlet Allocation model, where each row is a vector of multinomial probabilities for words in a vocabulary. Each row corresponds to a topic, so if you have `K` topics, then the matrix has dimension `K * V`, where `V` is the size of the vocabulary.

A conventional way of visualizing the "topics", or particular multinomial distributions, is to report the words that are most probable in each topic.  I'd like to print out a K by 5 matrix-like data structure where each row of the matrix reports the top 5 most likely "tokens" in each topic and their corresponding probabilities.

Consider, for example, the following vocabulary and topic-term probability matrix:

```
require(MCMCpack) # for Dirichlet Distribution
numTopics <- 10
vocab <- c("coffee", "sunday", "bagel", "hangover", "regrets", "fun", "beer")
mtrx <- rdirichlet(numTopics, rep(1, length(vocab)))
colnames(mtrx) <- vocab
```

If we interpret the `i-j` entry of matrix to be the probability of the token indexed by `j` (in the vocabulary) occurring in topic `i`, then I'd like to sort each row of `mtrx` in order of probability and attach the names of the relevant tokens so that the labels are still correct.

Could someone recommend a suitable data-structure for this task?

Comment: This isn't going to happen with a single matrix. You might consider using two matrices (perhaps collected in a list) where one tracks the probabilities and the other tracks the word. You could even give it its own S3 class and methods to make it easier to work with. Or you could always just use a list containing named vectors and forget about matrices altogether. It all depends on how you want to extract values out of this structure.

Comment: @MrFlick - my objective with this endeavor is to summarize the topics in a single table or grid, eventually to be written to CSV and displayed in a table in LaTeX.